# How to keep button ratio in a BoxLayout in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When using a BoxLayout in kivy and adding some button widgets using BoxLayout.add_widget() my buttons strech accordingly to the size of the boxes and the numebr of buttons. If my BoxLayout has an horizzontal orientation, the more buttons I add, the more they get shorter along the horizontal axis.

Since my buttons have an image, I would like the buttons to lengthen or shorten the more I add or remove widgets but keep a certain shape, perhaps square. So if the length is reduced, the width will do the same

If I'm not mistaken, using images instead they keep their shape without having to modify parameters (putting only the path to the image). The problem is that I don't know how to activate a certain function by clicking on the images.

Looking at the official documentation I can't find a solution to my problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the `ButtonBehavior` [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#example).

Comment: @JhonAnderson The links you provided me contain a lot of useful information. I had never looked at it thanks! Following the directions I got around the problem by building an image that acts as a button.